# Problem predicting test values with python sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I did a code to predict Y values, X and Y are arrays of the same lenght

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

plt.scatter(X,Y,1)
regr2 = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(10), Ridge())
regr2 =regr2.fit(X[:,np.newaxis], Y)
y_pred=regr2.predict(X[:,np.newaxis])
plt.plot(X, y_pred, color='red')
plt.show()
```

It works and it is a good approximation
But when I do it with test values and train values it shows an exponential when I plot it which it is not supposed to do.

In fact the y_pred1 is the X_test plus a small decimal number

```
plt.scatter(X_test,Y_test,1)

X_train=X[0:int(0.8*len(X))]
X_test=X[int(0.8*len(X)):]
Y_train=Y[0:int(0.8*len(X))]
Y_test=Y[int(0.8*len(X)):]

regr3 = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(10), Ridge())
regr3 =regr3.fit(X_train[:,np.newaxis], Y_train)
y_pred1=regr3.predict(X_test[:,np.newaxis])
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred1, color='red')
plt.show()
```

I tried several things, even testing the prediction with the train values and in this case too it plot an exponential instead of an approximation of the points.

Thank in advance!

Comment: `plt.plot()` is a line plotting function. Did you want `plt.scatter()`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do the train/test split manually instead of using sklearn's `train_test_split()`? Your method (in addition to being written wrong as pointed out by @Qudus) will not do any random selection, which will be a problem if your array isn't already randomized

Comment: Using  plot was an error but replacing it did not solve the problem. I did this because I want to predict something in time so I need to take the first 80% as training values and the last 20% as test values. Why will it be a problem?

Comment: I understand now, I wasn't aware that it's a time-series problem. If it were not time series, that would not be a good way to split your train-test sets, which is why I mentioned it. Given that, time series can be tricky, as it tends to do as you stated and keep extrapolating in a certain direction. You may be able to do cross validation with [time series split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) to get a better estimator, or try different models

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841167/how-to-predict-time-series-in-scikit-learn) is a discussion on doing time-series in pandas and scikit

Comment: Honestly, a large portion of your problem would be solved if you just used sklearn's built-in `train_test_split()` method

Answer (score 0):

Fix Y_train

```
Y_train=Y[0:int(0.8*len(X))]
```

Comment: I changed it but still have a wrong approximation. Now the curve look like an exponential.